# When text of Edit-Text is null

Tags: java, android

I using **TextInputEditText** in my app.

I want to send a *Toast* when text of that is null. I want show it when a button clicked. how can I do it?

Comment: Please add more information regarding your problem.  Do you have a button to submit such text? Otherwise, you might need to listen for changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an if statement to check if it's null then send Toast.

```
 if (textInputEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "This Edittext is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem was solved!

Answer (score 1):

you can access the text value inside of it by using getText() methode.
however if no text is inside it returns an empty string(not null)

so you should check if it returns empty string ( "" ) then make a toast like below

```
Toast.makeText(this, null, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```